# Divisor Arithmetic

Tags: number-theory

The product of the proper positive integer factors of $n$ can be written as $n^{(ax+b)/c}$, where $x$ is the number of positive divisors $n$ has, $c$ is a positive integer, and the greatest common factor of the three integers $a$, $b$, and $c$ is 1. What is $a+b+c$?

I know that this works with the divisors of 24
24 has 8 divisors
So x=8, a=1, b=10, c=6
$24^3=13824=24^{(8*1+10)/6}$

$\gcd(1,6,10)$

$a+b+c=1+10+6=17$

But it also works with 60
which with 60, $a+b+c=19$
I'm not sure what would be my final answer could someone help me? (also it seems like this could have infinite solutions)

Comment: Where the *heck* do you get this problem!  I can tell you that:If $n = \prod p_i^{k_i}$ is the prime factorization of $n$ then

$x = \prod (k_i + 1)-2$ is the number of proper factors.

And $\frac {\prod p_i^{\sum_{j=1}^{k_i} j}}n$ is the product of the proper divisors.  BUT to convert that and solve for $\frac {\prod p_i^{\sum_{j=1}^{k_i} j}}n=n^{\frac{ax + b}c}$ for some integers $a,b,c$ just seems like a pointless and directionless monster.

Comment: So if you can figure $n = \prod p_i^{k_i}$ and $x = \prod(k_i + 1) -2$ and $n^{(ax+b)/c} =\prod p_i^{k_i(ax+b)/c} \prod p_i^{\frac{k_i(k_i -1)}2}$ you are done.  Good luck

Comment: @RossMillikan: Intuitively I would expect neither $1$ nor the number itself to count as a "proper" factor. This matches the definition in [Mathworld](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ProperFactor.html), which contrasts it to "proper divisor".

Comment: @HenningMakholm: I had never seen that distinction.  I will update my answer.  It won't change much.

Comment: Is this from Brilliant.org? It's the type of problem you would find there. If so, consider including a link.

Answer (score 2):

You just showed one case where $n=24$ where it will naturally have infinite solutions. Look for a solution in all cases. Spoiler below.

> $a=1,b=-2,c=2$ solves all the cases. So $a+b+c=1$ is the solution.

Comment: That's indeed the correct answer, once the question is interpreted as: find $a,b,c$ such that *this* holds for all $n$. However, you should explain this a little bit, especially the less obvious case where $n$ is a square: for nonsquare $n$, each divisor $d$ can be paired with $n/d$, whereas for square $n$, the divisor $\sqrt{n}$ is alone and accounts for the additional factor $\sqrt{n}$ in the product of divisors, hence the missing $1/2$ in the exponent.

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut Not quite sure why you say "$\sqrt{n}$ accounts for the missing 1/2 in the exponent". $\quad$ Instead, I argue that it's "$n$ that accounts for it, regardless of whether $n$ is a square": The square of the product of all positive factors by your pairing is clearly $ n^x$, so the product of all positive factors is $n^{x/2}$ and so the product of all proper positive factors is $ n^{x/2 -1}$.

Comment: @CalvinLin Here is what I meant. The pairing does not work for square $n$: $x$ is even, except when $n$ is square (since $x=\prod (k_i+1)$ where the $k_i$ are the exponents of the prime divisors of $n$, $x$ is odd iff all $k_i$ are even). Therefore, when $n$ is not square, factors are paired together and their product (including $1\times n$) is $n^{x/2}$. When $n$ is square $x-1$ factors can be paired, and there remains $\sqrt n$ alone, so you get $n^{(x-1)/2}\times\sqrt{n}$, again including $1\times n$. All in all, the answer is always $n^{x/2-1}$.

Answer (score 1):

As long as $n$ is neither prime nor a perfect square, the product of its proper factors is of the form $n^y$ for some positive integer $y$. (In fact $y=x/2-1$). Then we need to solve
$$ \frac{ax+b}{c} = y $$
for coprime $a,b,c$. But that is always possible: You can choose any prime $p > x$ and then set
$$ a=1, \quad b = yp - x, \quad c = p $$
Then $a,b,c$ will even be *pairwise* coprime.

When $x=2y+2$, we get
$$ a+b+c % = 1 + yp - 2y - 2 + p
= (1 - 2y - 2) + (y+1)p $$
which means that there is an infinity of solutions for each (non-square, non-prime) $n$.

Answer (score 0):

As you say $24$ has $8$ positive divisors, so you need $\frac {8a+b}c=3$, which you can satisfy with $a=1,b=10,c=6$ or with $a=1,b=4,c=4$ and many other combinations

$60$ has $12$ positive divisors, so you need $\frac {12a+b}c=5$, which you can satisfy with $a=1,b=3,c=3$ or with $a=2,b=1,c=5$ and many other combinations.

I would just display these four solutions and <strike>punch the setter in the nose</strike>  complain to the setter for making a poor problem.

Comment: But the "proper factors" were the ones that were multiplied together on the left-hand side of the equation -- so on further thought it doesn't even matter whether we consider $1$ to be among them. The $x$ on the right-hand side counts "positive divisors" which includes both $1$ and $n$. (Yeah, this is a horribly inconsistent, confusing, patently unmotivated problem).

Comment: @HenningMakholm:  I see you are right.  I'll fix again.

Comment: The recent answer has the correct interpretation, I think, hence the unique solution: with $p^k$ for prime $p$ it's easy to get $b=-2a$ and $c=-b$, then by factoring out the common factor $a$, it's done. And it's then easy to prove it's valid for all $n$.